# React app not rerender after store state changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

My component is not rerendering after the store is changing.
I make sure that the store is actually changing by dropping him to the console with 
store.subscribe() and console.log(store.getState()) but still the component is not rerendering again.
I will appreciate your help.

**configureStore.js**

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import home from '../reducers/home';
import favorites from '../reducers/favorites';

export default () => {
    const store = createStore(combineReducers({
        home,
        favorites
    }))

    return store;
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './redux/store/configureStore';
import AppRouter from './router/AppRouter';

const store = configureStore();

const jsx = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <AppRouter />
    </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(jsx, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

**home.js (reducer)**

```
const homeDefaultState = {
    name: 'someName'
}

export default (state = homeDefaultState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'CHANGE_NAME':
            return {
                ...state,
                name: 'otherName'
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**home.js (action)**

```
export const changeName = () => ({
    type: 'CHANGE_NAME'
})
```

**Home.js (component)**

```
import React from 'react';

import configureStore from '../../redux/store/configureStore';
import { changeName } from '../../redux/actions/home';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const store = configureStore();

const handleName = () => {
    store.dispatch(changeName())
}

const Home = (props) => (
    <div className="home">
        <button onClick={handleName}>
            change name
        </button>

        {props.home.name}
    </div>
);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    home: state.home
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Home` component you initialize store for second time. And bound action to this second store

```
const store = configureStore();

const handleName = () => {
    store.dispatch(changeName())
}
```

At the same time with `connect()` you access store declared in `App.jsx`

Read from first but update second. Just remove second `store` and use `mapDispatchToProps`([second parameter passed](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#mapdispatchtoprops-object-dispatch-ownprops-object) to `connect()`) instead:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    home: state.home
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { handleName: changeName })(Home);
```